# delete records from a select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-delete

i need to delete some users by counting the column "command", if there are less then 5 entry, they should be deleted from the table "Users".

```
DELETE FROM public."Users" 
where telegram_nickname in (select telegram_nickname, 
                                   count (command) 
                            from public."Logs" 
                            group by telegram_nickname 
                            having count (command) > 5 
                            order by (count) desc)
```

The above query doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` operator requires that you have the same number of columns on the left side and and the right side. Your sub-query returns two columns, but you only compare it to one column on the left. You need to remove the `count(command)` from the sub-query's select list - it's not needed anyway.

Also: an `order by` in a sub-query used for an `IN` condition is useless (unless you apply e.g. an `distinct on ()` or a `limit` clause)

So you need to use:

```
DELETE FROM public."Users" 
where telegram_nickname in (select telegram_nickname
                            from public."Logs" 
                            group by telegram_nickname 
                            having count (command) > 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `count (command)` from `SELECT`. Your `SELECT` is selecting 2 columns whereas only 1 column should be passed to `IN` operator,

Remove `order by` as well. Its pointless when you have to delete something.

```
DELETE FROM public."Users" 
where telegram_nickname in (select telegram_nickname
                            from public."Logs" 
                            group by telegram_nickname 
                            having count (command) > 5 )
```